# How to make an object exist in the current context?

Tags: c#

I fully understand why this is happening, but I don't know how to solve it as my attempts all didn't work.

I'm loading a file using MsgReader. I need to catch exceptions.

```
try
{
    var message = MsgReader.Mime.Message.Load(fileInfo);
}
catch(IOException e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
        
if (message.Attachments != null) //if has attachments
{
    //...
```

This obviously fails as the object is created within the try. How can I instantiate the object but without having it load the file?

I've tried this before the try:

```
var message = new MsgReader.Mime.Message;
```

Error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   CS1526  A new expression requires an argument list or (), [], or {} after type

I've also tried variations of this, but I can't find the type I need to specify.

Answer (score 3):

As the error states, if you want to create a `new` object then you need parentheses to invoke the constructor:

```
var message = new MsgReader.Mime.Message();
```

*However*, in this case it looks like you don't actually *want* a `new` instance, but just to *declare* the variable:

```
MsgReader.Mime.Message message = null;
```

In this case the declaration just needs an explicit type specified because `var` won't be able to infer the type from just `null`.

Just be aware that if the code in the `try` fails then `message` will be `null` and can't be used/dereferenced.

(And, of course, remove the `var` keyword when assigning a value to the variable within the `try` block.)

Comment: Perfect thanks! Hit such a mental block with this one. Obvious when I think about it.